# Error when passing Oracle SYSTEM.DATA.DATATABLE result as parameter to another powershell script

Tags: oracle, powershell, system.data.datatable

I'm working on a script that is expected to perform the following:

1. Connect to Oracle DB and run main query to extract raw data. - Already working as unit tested
2. Import raw data to a Microsoft access database template (.mdb) - Working as unit tested but encountering an error when integrated with script 1.
3. Connect to MS Access data, run filtered (sub)queries and export results into separate excel tabs. - Already working as unit tested

*Directly running the (sub)queries on the Oracle database was out of option since the query being performed on the Oracle database (raw data) takes about 5 hours so raw data is imported to Microsoft access first for processing, and then running the (sub)queries.

I have already created the Powershell script for each one of the items and one master script which calls and supplies the arguments for each. They have been unit tested.

1 - 01.dbquery.ps1 `[Parameter: NONE; Returns: RAW DATA]`

2 - 02.mdbimport.ps1 `[Parameter: RAW DATA(from 1),MDB FILE Return: NONE]`

3 - 03.mdb export.ps1 `[Parameter: EXCEL FILE, MDB FILE; Return: NONE]`

master script.ps1

However, when integrating script 1 and 2, Im getting the error `System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingException: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Data.DataRow'.`
Note that script 1 returns System.Data.Datatable value from the queried result on the Oracle DB and I'm trying to figure out why script 2 does not seem to accept this value. I've also tried stating the type `System.data.datarow` on the parameter declaration but still to no avail as I'm getting the error

```
Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'RawData'. Cannot convert the "System.Data.DataRow System.Data.DataRow System.Data.DataRow System.Data.DataRow System.Data.DataRow System.Data.DataRow" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Data.DataRow".
```

Below are the code snippets for each script

**master script.ps1**

```
## Setup reusable variables (e.g. MDB, excel templates)
$scriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$Date=(get-date).tostring('MMddyyy')
$MdbFile =  $scriptPath+"\Pts on Spans Analysis "+$date+".mdb" 
$ExcelFile = $scriptPath+'\Pts on Spans Action '+$date+'.xls'

## 01. Connect to Oracle DB and run main query for PS raw data
write("**Starting Oracle database query and storing results... -- "+(get-date))
$01dbquery = $scriptPath+"\01dbquery.ps1"
$01ret = Invoke-Expression "& `"$01dbquery`""
write("**Finished querying Oracle DB. -- "+(get-date)); write-host

## 02. Import raw data to MDB template (Microsoft access) -- ImportedPtsonSpans
write("**Starting import of PS raw data to MDB... -- "+(get-date))
$02mdbimport = $scriptPath+"\02mdbimport.ps1"
Invoke-Expression "& `"$02mdbimport`" -RawData $01ret -MdbFile `"$MdbFile`""
write("**Finished import of PS raw data. -- "+(get-date)); write-host

## 03. Process MS Access data and export into excel
write("**Starting export of processed PS data into Excel... -- "+(get-date))
$03mdbexport = $scriptPath+"\03mdbexport.ps1"
Invoke-Expression "& `"$03mdbexport`" -ExtractName `"$ExcelFile`" -MdbFile `"$MdbFile`""
write("**Finished data export. Pts and Span Extract Completed -- "+(get-date)); write-host
```

**01dbquery.ps1**

```
$scriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition    
function Get-DataTable
{
    Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection]$conn,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$sql
    )
    $cmd = New-Object System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand($sql,$conn)
    $da = New-Object System.Data.OracleClient.OracleDataAdapter($cmd)
    $dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
    [void]$da.Fill($dt)
    return ,$dt
}

## Initiate database credential variables
<more codes here>

## Setup database connection
<more codes here>

## Perform database queries and store results
$QueryPath = $scriptPath+"\queries\main\Pts Span Qry.txt"
$Query = get-content $QueryPath | out-string

# *** Entry Point to Script ***
$RawData = Get-DataTable $conn $Query ; $RawData
```

**02mdbimport.ps1**

```
param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$RawData,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$MdbFile
)
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

$scriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition    

Function Connect-Database($MdbFile, $Tables)
{
  <codes>
} #End Update-Records

Function Update-ImportedPtsonSpans
{
 <codes>
} #End Update-ImportedPtsonSpans

# *** Entry Point to Script ***
## Perform import of raw data into Microsoft Access Database (MDB)
$Tables = "ImportedPtsonSpans"
# Test if raw data is passed
write-host Start Test raw data and MdbFile
$RawData
$MdbFile
write-host End Test raw data and MdbFile
#
Connect-DataBase -MdbFile $MdbFile -tables $Tables
```

**03mdbexport.ps1**

```
param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$ExtractName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$MdbFile
)
$scriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
Function Export-Data($Queries,$MdbFile,$ExtractName)
{
    <codes>        }
} #End Export-Data

Function Export-To-Excel($ExtractName,$QueryName,$CurResult)
{
    <codes>    } # End Export-To-Excel

# *** Entry Point to Script ***
$QueryPath = $scriptPath+"\queries\*.txt"
$Queries = Get-ChildItem $QueryPath
Export-Data -Queries $Queries -MdbFile $MdbFile -ExtractName $ExtractName
```

Thanks in advance!